# PHP 7 & MSSQL PDO: Calling a stored procedure with input and output params

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo, php-7

In PHP5  I used to bind Params like this:

`mssql_bind($stmt,'@BIAC_MEMBER',$inMemberID,SQLVARCHAR); //Input`
`mssql_bind($stmt,'@BIAC_RESULT',$outResult,SQLVARCHAR,true); //Output`

Since `mssql_*` got removed in PHP7 and you need to work with PDO now I changed my connection to this:

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL MyStoredProc(?, ?, ?, ?)");`

According to the PHP doc you can bind using  `$stmt->bindParam();` but they have not mentionened if and how you can bind input aswell as output params.

Is it possible to specify multiple in-/output params, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your params following the documentation pages :

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Namely using the following code :

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL MyStoredProc(?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
$value = 'hello';
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $return_value\n & $value";
?>
```

This has one out parameter and one in/out paramater, so should be easily adaptable for your needs. They key is simply to setting the correct data_type and length value( arguments 3 & 4 in bindParam() )

Full list of datatypes:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Note: this is taken from docs and adapted, but I Haven't tested it, but hopefully at the very least it sets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In `PDO` you can use `bindParam`. Here's a full example of how to use `bindParam`.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSNY3_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0023502.html

Good Luck!